# How to find the quantity of an item that is in a different list and alter it?

Tags: python

In this program I am trying to make an inventory program. Under option (3) titled "Update Inventory" you type in an item for the list `name`, then you are prompted to either add to the existing quantity in the list `qty` or subtract from it.

For example if I have five items in `name` and the corresponding quantity in `qty`. How do I find item 3, and update the quantity by adding to or subtracting from the current amount.

Full program code (only looking for help on how to write option 3):

```
name = []
qty = []

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty


def menuDisplay():
    print ('=============================')
    print ('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print ('=============================')
    print ('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print ('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print ('(3) Update Inventory')
    print ('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print ('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print ('(99) Quit')
    CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    menuSelection(CHOICE)

def menuSelection(CHOICE):

    if CHOICE == 1:
        print('Adding Inventory')
        print('================')
        new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        name.append(new_name)
        new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
        qty.append(new_qty)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print('Removing Inventory')
        print('==================')
        removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
        indexdel = name.index(removing)
        name.pop(indexdel)
        qty.pop(indexdel)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print('Updating Inventory')
        print('==================')
        item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
        update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
    if update >= 0:
        
        print()
    elif update <= -1:
        print()
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
```

I have shortened the code as I believe this is the minimum code as possible to duplicate my issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question an provide a [mre] that contains only code directly related to your question.

Comment: I believe I have now, you need option 1 to input the data you are editing in option 3.

Comment: Storing inventory in two lists is not the optimal choice. Did you consider using a dictionary for that? Or, if you expect your data to be large, what about the database as SQL?

Comment: I did not think of having a dictionary, what code would I need to change to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not suggest using multiple lists to store related items. A `dictionary` is probably your best bet, especially when working with an inventory system - in an inventory, every item has a unique attribute. Dictionaries store key/value pairs, which is perfect for something like this. Using two lists can be detrimental; one small bug could derail the entire system. Something like this will illustrate the simplicity of using a dictionary over multiple lists:

```
inventory = {'apples':0, 'bananas':0, 'oranges':0}

item = input("Enter the item to update: ")
qty = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))

inventory[item] += qty
```

However, if you are set on using two lists, this will serve your purpose:

```
name = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges']
qty = [0,0,0]

item = input("Enter the item to update: ")
update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))

qty[name.index(item)] += update
```

Assuming your lists are associated 100% with each other, the above will use the index position of the item and update that quantity in the other list.